# TCP establish a connection

Tags: networking, tcp

I wonder why we 3 way handshaking , why we just do connection with 2 way handshaking .

Comment: [why not a two way handshake, why a three way handshake](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2000522).

Comment: @Dukeling it's said that at step 2 , the server send it's sequence number ,why each of them has sequence number ? i think that both of them agree on a common sequence number .

Comment: @user3137879 How would a common seqno work if you consider that packets may arrive out-of-order? There is no in-order guarantee in packets delivery.

Comment: You need two sequence numbers: one in each direction, as they are independent, and initialized by the sender in each case for security reasons. Also, both sides need to know that the connection succeeded. You can't accomplish that in a two-way handshake. (Actually you can't accomplish it at all, see the 'two-army problem', but making it three-way helps.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Ans](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/643058-tcps-3-way-handshake-why-not-2-way/#entry5061587) :

> The ACK is accompanied by sequence numbers.
>    The RFC is pretty clear on the handshake:
>
> 1) A --> B SYN my sequence number is X
>
> 2) A <-- B ACK your sequence number is X
>
> 3) A <-- B SYN my sequence number is Y
>
> 4) A --> B ACK your sequence number is Y
>
> Steps 2 and 3 are combined in a single packet.
>
> The thing about it is that step 4 is also what is used to move the TCP window.
>   By including that step you are using the regular protocol in the 
>   initialization process.  It is basically just zeroing out the transmission windows.
>
> You aren't blocked from sending data along with step 4.
>
> You could send data with your first ACK if you wanted to, essentially saying 
>   "I received packets up to Y, here is some data".

[image]

As we can see in the above image, Client side connection completes when client receives ACK from server but server side connection still remains in incomplete state, until server not receives ACK from client side.

As @EJP, said in the comment above we need two sequence numbers, since common sequence numbers lead to many inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

"Because, if Server B never hears back from Client A, how does Server B know that Client A can "hear" what it's saying? "

http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2000522